# The double quotient of SU(N) by its diagonal maximal torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$The special unitary group $\SU(N)$ contains $T^{N-1}$ as a maximal torus, which we take to be the diagonal subgroup of $\SU(N)$. Can we describe the double quotient space
$$
T^{N-1}\backslash \SU(N)/T^{N-1}
$$
in a nice way? Can we give a useful description of its polynomial functions in terms of the Peter–Weyl decomposition of $\SU(N)$?